# View Controller shows as pop-up

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

I want a normal segue, so no pop-up. But when I push the button to go to the next ViewController, it shows as ab pop-up. The buttons to the next ViewController is in a different storyboard than the ViewController I'd like to go to.
This is the code of the first ViewController:

```
import UIKit
//some other code

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
   //some other code
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
       //some other code
   }
   @objc private func ProceedTapped(){
       //Door naar storyboard van de daadwerkelijke app
       print("Proceed clicked")
    
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToAppIdentifier", sender: self)
   }
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)
   }  
}
```

And this is the code of the ViewController I'd like to go to:

```
import UIKit

class HomeScreen: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print("Home has loaded") 
    }
}
```

The kind of the segue of the "Storyboard Segue" is "Show (e. g. push)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to go to story board select the 2nd view controller and change presentation style to "Full Screen". Please check below image for reference[image]